# How to choose a selection in selector and update my table

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table where above I have a selector(with 2 options, oldeste and newest". With that when I choose "oldest" it puts the oldest elements above and when I choose newest it puts the newest alements above.
My table id in html is "Mytable" I have a field called Date, and this is my code.

```
  <form action="" method="post">
                 <center>  <b>Filter: <b><select name="select1">
                  <option value="value1">by Oldest</option>
                  <option value="value5">by Newest</option>
                </select></center>
                <br>
                <center> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Filter"/> </center> 
                <br>
              </form>
              <?php
              if(isset($_POST['select1'])){
                $select1 = $_POST['select1'];
                switch ($select1) {
                  case 'value1':?>

    //something

                  <?php break; ?>
                  <?php case 'value2': ?>

    //something
                  <?php break; ?>

                  <?default:

                  break;
                }
              }
              ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First set id to select:
`<select name="select1" id="selectlist">`

Try something like this to get value:

`var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectlist");
var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;`

And now you know what you pick in selectedValue.

Then you must set onchange parametr:

`onchange="function()"`

And make function in javascript to edit.